# Google Cloud Storage HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Bad Request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am receiving this error `oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Bad Request` when I try to connect to a Google Cloud Storage bucket in any of my projects (all of which were working previously).

```
from gcloud import storage
client = storage.Client() 
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

I signed into my gcloud account through command line on a co-worker's laptop and the script connected to Cloud Storage fine. My co-worker then signed into his gcloud account on my computer and it did not work for him either. We assumed it was the server time issue that many other posts reference or something very wrong with my computer.

We ran `ntpdate` and got `8 Nov 12:00:38 ntpdate[3468]: no servers can be used, exiting` we also went through using `ntpd` but to no avail.

```
Project in       : Python 2.7 | 
OS               : MacOS Sierra v 10.12.1 |
Google cloud sdk : 133.0.0
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had checked my authentication with gcloud and had revoked and logged back in using these commands

`gcloud auth revoke` and `gcloud auth login` and then following the steps that come after that to get the authentication. **These steps did not work.**

I then dug through Google's not so friendly documentation for hours and got back to this page: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/google-cloud-auth.html

> If you're developing locally, the easiest way to authenticate is using the Google Cloud SDK:

`$ gcloud beta auth application-default login`

> Note that this command generates credentials for client libraries. To authenticate the CLI itself, use:

`$ gcloud auth login`

I have yet to finish readying what the difference between these two commands are but all of my projects now work again. Good luck

IN SHORT:
use `gcloud beta auth application-default login`

Comment: `gcloud auth login` is for the gcloud command. `gcloud beta auth application-default login` is for the SDK. that fact that they use different auth mechanisms is really obnoxious and frustrating. Also, the application-default command will generate a PLAIN TEXT NON-EXPIRING local key on your HDD. But gcloud, I believe, stores creds in an encrypted DB? I can't find the docs that explain how it works.